# Vue: linking components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If I have a `TodoList` component like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <InputText
        v-model="newTodoText"
        placeholder="New todo"
        @keydown.enter="addTodo"
    />
  ...
</template>
```

How do I change my `InputText` component to send the text back to this component?

```
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="input"
  >
</template>
```

The `addTodo` method exists, I just don't know how to link the text in `InputText` back to the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `keydown.enter` check in your `InputText` component instead. Then, you can do e.g. `@keydown.enter="emitEnterKeyPressed()` in your component instead. In this `emitEnterKeyPressed()` method, you can `$emit` an event along with the content of the text input and then respond to this event in your parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <InputText
        v-model="newTodoText"
        placeholder="New todo"
        @enter_key_pressed="addTodo"
    />
  ...
</template>
```

InputText:

```
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="input"
    v-model="v_model_text"
    @keydown.enter="emitEnterKeyPressed()"
  >
</template>
```

Your `addTodo` can then look something like:

```
addTodo: function(input_text) {
    //do something with the input_text from TextInput component
}
```

And your `emitEnterKeyPressed` would look something like:

```
emitEnterKeyPressed: function() {
    this.$emit('enter_key_pressed', this.v_model_text);
}
```

The reason you would want to do this is because individual components should operate fairly autonomously in order to ensure reusability. If you need these components to communicate between one another, then it's important to follow the appropriate procedure for this. In particular, parent-to-child communication should be handled through `props` and watching for changes in their values, whereas child-to-parent communication should be handled via `$emit`ing events (with or without data) and handling them using parent methods.

Comment: I get your idea for sure, but I just get `[Vue warn]: Property or method "v_model_text" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` warnings now.

Comment: You'll need to define the appropriate data field in your component. I highly recommend reviewing the documentation in more depth. I also recommend trying to use Vue.js in its simplest form, without the use of importing and exporting components, so that you fully understand how Vue works without the additional complexity. It should help to alleviate some of your confusion. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/